# protected ifstream member

Tags: c++, get, protected

I am close to completion of my first OOP project, coming from a C background. I was wondering a design issue related to some ifstream object that I use in the base class to open a file. After that I would like to use the same stream to do further operation by the derived classes. I defined only this member as a protected one so I could reach that in the derived classes, protected breaks the encapsulation(I would like to earn good habits), should I define some getter function to return a reference to a stream object? Since the ifstream objects are not copiable, that might be a problem, first thing I see...

Best,
Umut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected` is ideal for *preserving* encapsulation, if it's integral to your design that the derived classes have the same I/O functionality as the base class.

Encapsulation does not mean everything has to be `private`, it means that each data or code member of a given class is visible only to the minimal set of class users to achieve the class's designed purpose.  In other words, don't make everything `public` just because that makes it easier to code.

You would only need a `public` getter if you wanted to expose the I/O function of the base and derived classes to code outside of the hierarchy.  Returning a reference does not imply any copy, by the way.

Comment: And Getter is breaking encapsulation even more (if it's public)

Comment: Thx, Steve, Could you please make this "You would only need a public getter if you wanted to expose the I/O function of the base and derived classes to code outside of the hierarchy" a bit clear maybe a short example.

Comment: @Drakosha - that's purely a value judgment, cannot be sure this is A Bad Thing without knowing more about the class's purpose.

Comment: @Umut - you already postulated getter as a way for the derived classes to access the stream.  That would work but `protected` data member is (probably) OK and simpler.  If non-derived classes have to access the stream directly (and this may not be a good idea as noted by @Drakosha) you could implement a `public` getter.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: i mean public getter as almost as bad as public member in encapsulation breaking, do u disagree?

Comment: Yes, if you make something public it does not matter how.  Public getter is worse in some ways, because it allows your code to appear decoupled (by using the result of the getter), and actually not be.